# Thunderbird will not retrieve email under Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu, 16.04, thunderbird

I initially upgraded a Sony VAIO VGN-NR498E from Xubuntu 14.04 64-bit to Xubuntu 16.04 64-bit.  Prior to upgrading, Thunderbird was fully functional on this laptop.  After upgrade, Thunderbird would launch, however it would not completely launch; it would not show the current email from the email data file, nor retrieve new email.  Thunderbird stopped at this point, and the "loading icon" spun continually.

I found if I had Thunderbird already open to the same account and same data file on another device, then it would launch in Xubuntu 16.04 64-bit to the point where I could read the email.  (NOTE: I share the email data file with all my computers in my network, so I have access to the same email regardless which computer I'm on.  This has worked flawlessly for a couple of years.)  I could send email once Thunderbird completely launched, however it would not store the sent email in the SENT folder.  I was not able to delete any email, even after closing Thunderbird on the other computer, so file sharing/ownership was not an issue.

I then re-loaded Xubuntu 16.04 64-bit, only this time I had it completely delete all previous files on the hard drive; what I refer to as a "clean load."  The problem is still there, identical to the above description.

The email account uses POP3, rather than IMAP.  When Thunderbird is launched after it is already running on another device, and it retrieves the stored data files, it shows the message "building summary file for INBOX" in the status bar during the retrieving process.  I can then read all the email once this finishes, however all the same problems as indicated above remain.

Comment: Additional note: I tested the 32-bit version of Xubuntu 16.04 on a separate computer (Dell Latitude D620).  Thunderbird appears to work correctly in the 32-bit environment on that particular laptop, although I did not test all the functions.  Perhaps the problems I experienced were due to Xubuntu 16.04 being installed on a 64-bit computer? (NOTE: I did use the 64-bit version of Xubuntu 16.04 for the installation on the 64-bit laptop.)